# How to format a date from yyyy-MM-dd to dd.MM.yyyy

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I have a string with this data:

```
2011-09-13 22:20:00
```

I want to have this data:

```
13.09.2011
```

Additional I want to have the string "Today" when the date is today.

How to do this in Objective C?
I tried it the last 1 hour, but don't get it:

```
//Date basteln
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString* str = [[ens objectForKey:@"datum_server"] substringToIndex:10];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
NSDate *now = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"%@", now);
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];

[dateFormat release];
[now release];
```

So I tried to cut of the time, convert it with the wrong format to the right format.
But it crashed in a SIGBART.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't release

```
now
```

This is an autoreleased object, you are over releasing it and this is causing your crash.

Answer (score 0):

You should always release those object which you own it by using **'init', 'copy' 'alloc', 'new', 'copy', or 'mutableCopy'**. so there you do not need to release the date object because you did not own that.

Comment: Just little explanation so next time you will come to know which object i should release and which one is not. :)